# Cassandra and lucene: User management in docker

Tags: docker, cassandra, lucene

I am using a Docker image to run cassandra with the lucene plugin: https://hub.docker.com/r/cpelka/cassandra-lucene/

I am running this image on the Google container engine.

Everything works fine, except the user management. When I log in with the cassandra/cassandra user, it seems to have no rights. I cannot list users, and I cannot change passwords.

I can access and edit tables fine though, it just does not seem to be a superuser.

Something I read is that I have to enable password auth. I added the setting to my cassandra.yaml, but I cannot restart my cassandra service. Hell, if I run service cassandra stop, it takes a while and stops, and then I can still connect to my DB remotely. I think the docker image runs the Database in ways that I do not understand with my one day of cassandra experience. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and good day,

Dries